# Did wages get paid in pubs?

Tags: economy, social-history, united-kingdom

I recall hearing that in the past in Britain and Ireland, some workers (perhaps miners?) got their weekly wages paid out in the pub, much to the dismay of their wives.  I don't remember where I heard or read it, and I can't find a reference to it now.  Was there any era / branch / area where such was common practice?

Comment: Validation that it was at least a tradition for miners to go to the pub after their shift: https://libcom.org/history/british-miners-strike-19841985-retrospective-view-some-events-st-johns-colliery-maesteg-

Comment: A few references: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22paid+in+the+pub%22

Comment: Hat tip to @called2voyage; I tried to search for that and I couldn't find it. I bow to your superior google-fu!

Comment: @called2voyage Ah, I searched on Google Web Search and didn't get relevant results.